# Como desenhar linhas acompanhando a movimentação do mouse?

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Preciso de um `JPanel`, que desenhe linhas  seguindo o ponteiro do mouse enquanto o mesmo é arrastado, e quando liberado ele precisa parar de desenhar.

Acontece que, sempre que é desenhada duas ou mais linhas seguidas, elas conectam- se às linhas anteriores, isso não deveria ocorrer.

Como conseguir arrastar linhas sem que elas se liguem sozinha, semelhante ao software Paint da Microsoft?

Eis o meu código:

```
    package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

//Essa classe tem o objetivo de imitar o recurso de desenhar linhas do softwere paint, da Microsoft.

public class DrawingSketch extends JFrame {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5661286812709693531L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel draft;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private ArrayList<Integer> cX = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> cY = new ArrayList<>();
    private Integer xa;
    private Integer ya;
    protected int mX;
    protected int mY;
    public int i;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DrawingSketch frame = new DrawingSketch();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DrawingSketch() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        draft = new Draft();
        draft.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
                //As coordenadas x e y estão sendo armazenadas nas coleções cX e CY respectivamente.
                cX.add(e.getX());
                cY.add(e.getY());
                draft.repaint();
            }
        });
        draft.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(draft, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        draft.setLayout(null);
    }

    public class Draft extends JPanel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4886600019364448097L;

        public Draft() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (i = 1; i < largerBeetweenXeY(cX.size(), cY.size()); i++) {
                // x é o valor final de x.
                x = cX.get(i);
                //y é o valor final de y.
                y = cY.get(i);
                // xa é o valor inicial de x. 
                xa = cX.get(i - 1);
                // ya é o valor inicial de y.
                ya = cY.get(i - 1);

                // Observação, se for usada a formula: xa = cX.get(i) e ya = cY.get(i), sem o i -1, o que é obtido e uma sequência de pontos
                // desconexos, ou seja, com espaço vazio entre eles. As formulas xa = cX.get(i - 1) e ya = cY.get(i - 1), garantem que a linha
                // fique perfeita, no entanto, com o traçado de duas ou mais linhas, as linhas se ligam, o que não deveria acontecer.

                Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D)g;
                RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g1.setRenderingHints(rh);
                g1.drawLine(xa, ya, x, y);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param int size valor de x.
     * @param int size2 valor de y.
     * Verifica o limite da iteração em paintComponent.
     */
    public int largerBeetweenXeY(int size, int size2) {
        if (size > size2) {
            return size;
        } else {
            return size2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O método mais prático se encontra mais ao fim da resposta, após a **Atualização**

---

O que ocorre é que você salva todas as coordenadas na lista, e cada vez que termina e começa uma nova linha, o [`paintComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-) redesenha a tela utilizando todas as coordenadas armazenadas, inclusive a coordenada final de uma linha e a inicial de uma outra, pois ele não sabe diferenciar isso.

Uma forma interessante de resolver isso que encontrei é inserir "coordenadas negativas", para que assim seja possível verificar quando uma linha terminou e quando outra começou.

Para facilitar trabalhar com coordenadas, é recomendável que você trabalhe com a classe [`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), assim não há necessidade de criar 2 listas para armazenar cada eixo de coordenada.

Crie uma variável na sua classe principal que represente uma lista de coordenadas:

```
private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

é nela que vamos armazenar as coordenadas, inclusive as "nulas".

No método [`mouseDragged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-), adicione cada coordenada por onde o mouse se arrastar dentro da área do componente à lista, e depois force o redesenho. Alterando no seu código, ficou da forma abaixo:

```
draft.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

        points.add(e.getPoint());
        draft.repaint();
    }
    
});
```

No método  [`mouseReleased()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-), adicione a coordenada final e a coordenada "negativa" à lista. Este ponto com coordenadas negativas é que nos servirá de referência para identificarmos que uma linha terminou.

```
draft.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //adiciona uma coordenada "nula" para ignorarmos
        //no paintComponent
        points.add(e.getPoint());
        points.add(new Point(-1, -1));
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
});
```

Agora, no `paintComponent()`, precisamos controlar a forma como as linhas são desenhadas. A forma que utilizei foi parecida com a sua, pegando um ponto e seu sucessor para criar cada segmento das linhas. O "pulo do gato" é verificar se a coordenada seguinte da atual iteração é "negativa", se for, pulamos 2 iterações, pois não queremos ligar o final de uma linha com o começo da outra:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < points.size() - 1) {
        Point currentPoint = points.get(i);
        Point nextPoint = points.get(i + 1);

        if (nextPoint.x != -1 && nextPoint.y != -1) {
            Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
            RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g1.setRenderingHints(rh);
            g1.drawLine(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
            i++;

        } else {
            // quando as coordenadas do ponto seguinte forem (-1, -1),
            // pulamos essa iteração para evitar que a linha anterior
            // seja ligada a nova linha que está sendo desenhada
            i += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, o laço dará um salto entre o ponto final de uma linha e o ponto negativo, indo direto ao ponto inicial da outra linha.

Sua classe com as alterações ficará bem mais limpa e simplificada, veja:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

//Essa classe tem o objetivo de imitar o recurso de desenhar linhas do softwere paint, da Microsoft.

public class DrawingSketch extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5661286812709693531L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel draft;

    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DrawingSketch frame = new DrawingSketch();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DrawingSketch() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        draft = new Draft();
        draft.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

                points.add(e.getPoint());
                draft.repaint();
            }

        });
        draft.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // adiciona uma coordenada nula para ignorarmos
                // no paintComponent
                points.add(e.getPoint());
                points.add(new Point(-1, -1));
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(draft, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        draft.setLayout(null);
    }

    public class Draft extends JPanel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4886600019364448097L;

        public Draft() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
    
            int i = 0;
            while (i < points.size() - 1) {
                Point currentPoint = points.get(i);
                Point nextPoint = points.get(i + 1);
    
                if (nextPoint.x != -1 && nextPoint.y != -1) {
                    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
                    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    g1.setRenderingHints(rh);
                    g1.drawLine(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
                    i++;
    
                } else {
                    // quando as coordenadas do ponto seguinte forem (-1, -1),
                    // pulamos essa iteração para evitar que a linha anterior
                    // seja ligada a nova linha que está sendo desenhada
                    i += 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Atualização

Há uma maneira bem mais fácil e prática de se fazer isso, sem precisar ficar armazenando e redesenhando uma lista de pontos na tela. A solução é utilizar [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), que nada mais é uma representação em forma de imagem do desenho. Assim, o trabalho do `paintComponent()` é bem menor do que ficar iterando uma lista com inúmeros pontos.

Deixo o código abaixo com comentários nas mudanças:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draft extends JPanel {

    //usaremos para armazenar e desenhar novas imagens
    private BufferedImage bfImage;
    //usaremos para desenhar as linhas conforme movimentacao
    //do mouse na tela
    private Point oldPoint = null;
    private Point newPoint = null;
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4886600019364448097L;

    public Draft() {

        //crio uma instancia de bufferedimage do mesmo tamanho do painel
        bfImage = new BufferedImage(getSize().width, getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
                //armazenamos o novo ponto arrastado
                //atualizamos a imagem na tela
                //invertemos os pontos, pois após tela desenhada
                //o ponto atual passa a ser antigo
                newPoint = e.getPoint();
                updateImage();
                oldPoint = newPoint;
            }

        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //ao liberar o mouse, armazenamos o ponto atual para finalizar
                //o desenho da atual linha e "limpamos" as duas referencias de pontos                    
                newPoint = e.getPoint();
                updateImage();
                newPoint = null;
                oldPoint = null;
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                //ao pressionar o mouse, verificamos se o ponto antigo existe
                //pois ele é o ponto de partida para desenhar o primeiro segmento
                //da nova linha
                if (oldPoint == null) {
                    oldPoint = e.getPoint();
                }
            }

        });
    }
    
    //sobrescrevi o método getSize para que o tamanho do painel possa
    //ser informado corretamente ao bufferedImage
    @Override
    public Dimension getSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 350);
    }

    private void updateImage() {
        //se o ponto atual não for nulo, criamos um grafico no buffer e desenhamos o
        //segmento da linha atual, forçando o redesenho da tela com repaint()
        if (newPoint != null) {

            Graphics2D g2 = bfImage.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.drawLine(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
            g2.dispose();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //apenas passamos o buffer para o paintcomponent desenhar
        //o que está nele.
        g.drawImage(bfImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

E para usar, basta apenas adicionar uma instancia na sua tela:

```
seuFrame.add(new Draft());
```

Com essas mudanças, aumentam a possibilidades, inclusive de salvar uma imagem como arquivo, recuperar um desenho já salvo, dentre outras que o msPaint já faz. :)

Comment: @jsantos1991 opa, passou despercebido isso, corrigido, obrigado pelo alerta :D