# Desenhar um JPanel dentro de um JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de saber como faço desenhar uma linha dentro de um `JPanel` que fica dentro de um `JFrame`, ao pressionar um botão. A disposição do botão e do `JPanel` dentro do `JFrame` é exemplificada na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o botão é pressionado o programa deve desenhar uma linha do ponto 10,10 ao ponto 100,100 do `JPanel`. Já vi exemplos como o código abaixo para desenhar linha.

```
public void desenha( Graphics g ){
   g.setColor(red);
   g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

O problema é que não sei onde utilizar esse método para que a linha seja desenhada no `JPanel`, e somente quando o botão for pressionado.

Códigos:
Classe Principal:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tela t = new Tela();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Classe Tela:

```
public class Tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Tela() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        botao = new javax.swing.JButton();
        viewport = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        botao.setText("desenha");
        botao.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        viewport.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        viewport.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 3));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout viewportLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(viewport);
        viewport.setLayout(viewportLayout);
        viewportLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            viewportLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 361, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        viewportLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            viewportLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 231, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(142, 142, 142)
                        .addComponent(botao))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(viewport, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(botao)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(viewport, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void botaoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JButton botao;
    public static javax.swing.JPanel viewport;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** do seu codigo para que seja possivel te ajudar.

Comment: Pergunta editada com o código

Comment: Agora nao está claro como as figuras serao desenhadas.

Comment: É justamente isso que não sei como fazer, preciso desenhar uma figura qualquer dentro do JPanel ao clicar no botão, mas não tenho nem ideia de que método criar ou como criar.

Comment: Desenhar como? Quando?

Comment: Pode ser uma linha. Ao pressionar o botão uma linha dentro desse JPanel deve ser desenhada. Devo criar algum método para desenhar essa forma? Devo usar alguma biblioteca específica?

Comment: Sugiro que edite a pergunta e tente explicar melhor o que pretende fazer, porque nos comentarios voce ta pedindo algo bem diferente da pergunta.

Comment: A resposta a sua pergunta é que você pode criar uma subclasse de `JPanel` sobreescrevendo o método `paintComponent(Graphics)`. Veja nas perguntas que marquei como duplicata mais detalhes de como fazer isso.

Comment: Eu já respondi algo parecido aqui no site, mas era sobre desenhar conforme o movimento do mouse, dá uma olhada [**neste link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190340/28595) e bons estudos ;)

Comment: Ok, eu editei a pergunta para deixar ela mais específica, e vou olhar as respostas citadas por vocês para tentar implementar meu código. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Desenhar linhas tambem ja foi respondido aqui, pelo proprio Victor: [Como desenhar uma seta utilizando Java2D?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244647/como-desenhar-uma-seta-utilizando-java2d)

Comment: @AlexMauricio777 o que recomendo é que voce de uma lida nas perguntas que marcamos la no inicio, pq voce precisa ter uma nocao média de como funciona java2d para fazer isso sem ter problemas. É algo meio chatinho de manusear pq a API é complexa e, por vezes, confusa, mas nada impossivel de aprender, se tiver paciencia em ler e tentar entender como ela se comporta.